# Perl script logic converted to C#

Tags: c#, perl, hex, base64

I have a Perl script which I need to convert to C#.

But I have hit a speedbump.

The Perl script:

```
use Math::BaseCnv;
use Math::BaseCnv dig;
use XML::Simple;
use LWP::Simple; 
dig('url'); # select the right alphabet for the base64
my $parser = new XML::Simple;
my $url = 'http://10.0.2.128/api.xml';
my $content = get $url or die "Unable to get $url\n";
my $data = $parser->XMLin($content);
$StringData=$data->{dataField}; 
$DecValue = cnv('A'.substr($StringData,3,54),64,10);
dig('HEX');
$HexValue = cnv($DecValue,10,16);
```

**The value of $StringData is** `WS=3LCOBgCaxjQAADljIQEAAAG2FDADiAAB7QHKA6EyAPQgA1cC8gAA4E`

Length: 57

**The value of $DecValue is**

```
29461891743732702623135632717213292230507524331718660652410396996938709350973448271678550990392836
```

Length: 98

**And the value of $HexValue is**

```
DCB08E06009AC634000039632101000001B6143003880001ED01CA03A13200F420035702F20000E04
```

Length: 81

My issue is that I cant get the same `$DecValue` and `$HexValue` when using C#. I have searched Google dry and I am not even close to getting these values.

So it would be a greate help if anybody know a way to decode these values in C#?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What are the c# methods you've tried?

Comment: The first thing I do with the $StringData is to take the substring and at the 'A' in front. Giving: A3LCOBgCaxjQAADljIQEAAAG2FDADiAAB7QHKA6EyAPQgA1cC8gAA4E   And then the first thing I tried was to use Convert.FromBase64String(string). But I get an error telling me that the string is not a real base64 string. Even with out the A infront

Comment: The method I reached the furthest with is a Base64 lib from a guy called Exyll. There I get a byte array of 41 different numbers. but non of them match the right result. Lastly I have tried all the online converters I could find, all with the same result (Not the right one).

Comment: But I dont think that naming all the methodes I have used will help. I think it is more a question of me not knowing what exacthely is going on in the perl script when using the "cnv" method call..

Comment: You are getting different results since your script is using user defined convert table:
dig('url') is replacing the default 'b64' => ['0'..'9', 'A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', '.', '_']
That being used by all the other tests you've made.
See in the docs of the Perl package you are using:
https://metacpan.org/pod/release/PIP/Math-BaseCnv-1.4.75O6Pbr/BaseCnv.pm#dig-newd